# Border-Radius Not Working on IOS Despite Using Webkit

Tags: css

No matter what I do, I cannot seem to get the border radius to work on IOS devices. I have tried inline-styling, webkit, and so forth.

Here is a sample of my html and css

```css
.border-radius {
  border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
}

.border-radius2 {
  border-radius: 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
}

.nav-menu {
  background-color: rgba(178, 214, 222);
  display: flex;
  gap: 1.25rem;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.btn {
    padding: 0.35rem 1.1rem;
}

.btn-effect {
    border: 1px rgba(255,255,255,0) solid;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    outline: 1px solid;
    outline-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    outline-offset: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    transition: 1.25s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}
  
.btn-effect:hover {
    border: 1px rgba(255,255,255,.25) solid;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px rgba(221, 176, 213, 0.75), 0 0 15px rgba(221, 176, 213, 0.4);
    outline-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    outline-offset: 12px;
}

.btn-effect:active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px rgb(221, 145, 206), 0 0 15px rgba(221, 176, 213, 0.4);
    outline-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
    outline-offset: 0px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-menu" id="nav-menu-one">
            <li class="nav-item btn btn-effect border-radius"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item btn btn-effect border-radius"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Menu</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item btn btn-effect border-radius2"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Pics</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item btn btn-effect border-radius2"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Events</a></li>
        </ul>
```

The first two links are the desired outcome. However, on Safari, all the links appear as though they are using the example "border-radius2" class that I set up; It is as though there is no border-radius being applied

As you can see on the published site (still in development) (http://dessertbargilbert.com), it works perfectly fine on desktop in Chrome, but when testing on iPad, but buttons are squared off. Why would this be? The end goal is to get all class with "border-radius" to have the border applied correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please could you add a runnable snippet which demonstrates the problem. (SO is trying to build up a bank of useful questions and if your website eventually removes the problem your question will not be useful to future readers as the problem won't be there). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hello @AHaworth, I am currently at work, but will be able to add a more useful snippet later. Until last night, I was unaware what the root cause was, so I was not able to provide more information. But I will be sure to add more information later today. Thank you!

Comment: Hello @AHaworth, I just updated the post to included a runnable snippet demonstrating how it should look and how it looks on Safari

Answer (score 0):

I just played around with devtools in Safari (seems like it breaks on Safari desktop, not just iOS devices), and it seems like the `outline` property doesn't play nicely with `border-radius`.

It worked for me when I removed the `outline` and just kept the `border` and `border-radius`:

```
.btn-effect {
  /* Changing `border` color to a non-zero opacity */
  border: 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5) solid;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  /* Removing outline styles */
  /* outline: 1px solid; */
  /* outline-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5); */
  /* outline-offset: 0px; */
  text-shadow: none;
  transition: 1.25s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}
```

Comment: Hello @Anna. Thank you very much for your help in looking into this. Although, I noticed that since the Outline property was removed, it also removed the "offset out" affect as you hover over the button. I implemented your change to the "Events" and "About Us" buttons to compare the original vs the change. Do you have a way to get the original styling to stay? Thank you again!